# print numbers in ascending order from an n x m array whose rows are sorted

Tags: sorting, matrix, merge, complexity-theory

We have an n x m matrix whose rows are sorted, we need to print the numbers in the matrix in ascending order. The columns are not necessarly sorted. The solution that came to my mind was simple merging the rows in the matrix considering them as separate lists(basically the merging step in merge sort) which in merge sort takes O(n). I wanted to know what is the complexity of merging n separate arrays as in this case. I thought it would be O(n x m) but I am not sure.

Also, what would be a better way to print the numbers in ascending order? merging n lists at one go or merging 2 lists at a time till we consider all rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`What would be complexity? Its all depends how do you merge N arrays of M size!`

**Complexity of merging:**

- Merging two sorted `M` size array goes sequentially. So the complexity of this step is O(2M).

> For **`N rows`** where **`each row is sorted`** and **contains `M`elements.**

**If do it like (Merging linearly ):**

- Merging two rows first--you will get intermediate `2M size sorted array`.
- Merge `2M array` with another `row of N size` matix-- you will get `3M size sorted array`.

Merging in this manner `takes N steps` and `complexity would be O(N*M)`.

**Better way (divide-and-conquer technique):**

- Merge all pairs of two consecutive rows first (1,2), (3,4) this give you N/2 pairs of 2M size. in next step merge pairwise. as explain below.
- First make pair of two rows and `merge all N/2 pairs first and merge them`.
  e.g pair row(1,2); row(3,4); row(5,6) ......you will get `= N/2 pairs each of 2M size`.
- Now in next step, `make pair of two merged arrays each of size 2M from previous step` and then merge them--you will `get N/4 sorted array of 4M size`.((merging of 2M with other 2M array -> 4M and complexity is O(2M + 2M) = O(4M))

Progressively Merge all this intermediate `sorted arrays util you gets a single sorted array of size N*M`. And this time complexity will be **M*N*log(N)** as total `steps required is log(N)`.

I would like to recommend you to learn [merge-sort and its complexity.](http://www.slideshare.net/Ghaffar/sorting-presentation-791993)

Comment: That's incorrect. Dataset size is `M*N`. The data is `M` sorted sequences of length `N`. Complexity of natural merge sort (i.e., the one with sorted sequences) is `O(M*N)`.

Comment: You're not making sense. Please express yourself in a comprehensible way

Comment: Am I really doing wrong?! .. My request Please explain bit more so that I can understand.

Comment: Aid me so that we can provide correct solution. I think I couldn't understood your first comment correctly.

Comment: The 2D array can be arranged as a 1D array consisting of `M` sorted sequences of length `N`. Natural merge sort exploits these sorted sequences thus improving the general case complexity (`O(MNlogMN)`) to be `O(MN)`.

Comment: @icepack: Please comment back so that I can improve my answer..Which part i need to rewrite

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19651/discussion-between-grijesh-chauhan-and-icepack)

Comment: Thanks Grijesh and icepack. I'm more inclined to agree with icepack. It should be O(MN).

Comment: @miriaT : Even said for first it should be `O(N*M)` ..It for second method too?