# Conditional initialization in switch

Tags: c++, initialization, switch-statement

Why does this code fragment run fine

```
void foo(int i)
{
    switch(i) {
    case 1:
    {
        X x1;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
        X x2;
        break;
    }
}
```

whereas the following gives compilation error (initialization of 'x1' is skipped by 'case' label)?

```
void foo(int i)
{
    switch(i) {
    case 1:
        X x1;
        break;
    case 2:
        X x2;
        break;
    }
}
```

I understand that using braces introduces a new scope, hence storage will not be allocated for x1 till we hit its opening brace. But x2 is still initialized inside a case label without enclosing braces. Should this not be an error too?

I think initialization of x2 can be conditionally skipped in both the code fragments

Comment: I guess the error is when you declare x1 and x2 with the same name?

Comment: IDK, neither of those snippets result in an error for me, unless both variables have the same name...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall - I used VS2010 with default options. That gave me the mentioned error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1: Valid**

```
 case 1:
        {
        X x1;
        break;
        }
```

If it doesn't hit the condition, `x1` **can't be used by any further statements**, so there can't be a runtime error with this. `x1` doesn't try to exist outside braces.

---

**2: Invalid**

```
 switch(i) {
    case 1:
        X x1; //don't break
        i = 2;
        ...
        ...
        ...
     case 2:
        x1.someOperation()

 }
```

In the above, if `i` was `2` initially, you'd hit  `x1.someOperation()` before `X x1` which would construct the object.

**If it was** allowed to compile, it would throw a runtime error or not, depending upon whether the **case:1** was executed before 2, (and the object was constructed). Hence, it is disallowed by the compiler.

---

The same is allowed with Plain Old Data types which **cannot** have a user-defined constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you will get error only when `X` is a non-POD. If `X` is POD, then you will not get any error (when you don't use braces).

In case of non-POD, you **cannot** skip initialization of variables which are declared in the same scope. It results in compilation error when you don't use braces, because the `switch` lets you **skip** the initialization of such variables, yet at the same time it made them available to be used in all the `case` labels below it. That is dangerous.

Think along this line : if `i` is `2` , then the control will jump to the second `case` directly without initializing `x1`, and then you will be able to use `x1` in the second case even though it is not initialized. That doesn't make sense. Therefore, the language requires it to be an error.

---

By the way, to know what POD and non-POD is, see these topics:

- [Can't C++ POD type have any constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442717/cant-c-pod-type-have-any-constructor)
- [What is assignment via curly braces called? and can it be controlled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666321/what-is-assignment-via-curly-braces-called-and-can-it-be-controlled)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: See my answer. I added two links.

Comment: Nawaz :- Add full-form of POD , I can't understand error! look here http://codepad.org/ILDmG4Z9

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: POD means Plain Old Datatype. Please go through the links provided in my answer. POD is a well-known abbreviation in C++. Also, the code which you posted at codepad is compiled as C which is a different language. If you compile it as C++, it will compile fine, because that is a valid code. See this : http://codepad.org/DOGUwa9d

Comment: @Nawaz thanks for this answer - it's amazing sometimes how little I know - this helped me a lot.

Comment: @Nawaz: WaW! Excellent..I was unaware of this!...Thanks Nawaz

Comment: @Nawaz : Hi Nawaz - I saw your profile, linkedIn's also..You are interested in algorithm. Will please check my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410763/print-numbers-in-ascending-order-from-an-n-x-m-array-whose-rows-are-sorted/13411529#13411529

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is that each `case` is not a isolated scope: the code under `case 2` could refer the `x1` variable, since it has been declared before in the same scope (i.e.: the entire `switch` block): of course, it would not have been initialized, and it would result in an error.

Adding curly brackets you are actually splitting each `case`'s scope, allowing you to declare variables in `case 1` that can not be referred outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to create variables inside conditional statements. I recommend you to create the variable outside the `switch` statement and then asign values to it according with the condition on `i`:

```
void foo(int i) {

    X x1;

    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            x1 = ...;
            break;
        case 2:
            x1 = ...;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the version that fails, the declaration of `x1` doesn't go out of scope until several lines after the `case 2:` label. That's the problem. The declaration of `x2` is okay because there's no `case` label between the declaration and the end of its scope.